# How do you check if a particular KVO observer is currently registered?

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

Scenario:

I wish to remove a KVO:
    self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath:"readyForDisplay")

But I got this:

> ...reason: 'Cannot remove an observer...for the key path
>   "readyForDisplay" from ... because it is not registered as an
>   observer.'

I do I check to see if a KVO is registered prior to removing it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You need to keep track of your registration explicitly and ensure that you balance your registrations and removals.

Comment: Perhaps this can be solved in the future via ARC-type paradigm.

Comment: You mean something like a strongly retained object representing the observer which removes the observer on reallocation?

Comment: Yes.  I'm sure the compiler knows the scope of the observer registration better than the programmer; being that I get the runtime error.    So why can't we have an AOC (Automatic Observer Counting) as we have the ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)?

Comment: It's technically possible for sure, but if it isn't here now I wouldn't rely on it being here soon. You can roll your own version.